# Intellij "reformat code" modifies get-color-from-palette values (- separation)

Tags: intellij-idea, sass, angular-material, editorconfig

I want to avoid certain behavior in my IDE.

Using "**reformat code**" (i.e. **alt+ctrl+L** by default) in **Intellij** would separate color-hue value expression from the function `.get-color-from-palette()` from `_theming.scss` of `@angular/material`.
e.g.:

**Before reformat code:**

```
color: mat.get-color-from-palette($neutral, 50-contrast);
```

**After reformat code:**

```
color: mat.get-color-from-palette($neutral, 50 -contrast);
```

I searched everywhere but I don't know how I can change this behavior in the IDE.

Comment: what is `50-contrast` here? where does this value come from?

Comment: 50-contrast it’s a value as defined by the theming guide of angular material (https://material.angular.io/guide/theming)

Comment: the `getColorFromPalette` function argument should be either a number or a string according to function definition, and the hue value is normally enclosed in quotes according to https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#reading-hues-from-palettes... Please could you share examples where the passed value is used without quotes?